# How do I include unequal distances between x values in a ggerrorplot?

Tags: r, ggpubr

this is the first time I ask something, I've tried to find a solution in previous questions but I didn`t find it...I hope I did not miss anything, in that case I apologize.

I am plotting a ggerrorplot like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

mi_df <- data.frame(
  "month" = as.numeric(rep(c(0,1,2,12,15,48),30)) , 
  "sust" = as.factor(rep(c(rep(c("A","B"), each=6)), 15)),
  "vble" = as.numeric(rnorm(180)))

ggerrorplot(mi_df, x = "month", y = "vble", 
            desc_stat = "mean_sd", color = "sust", palette = c("black","grey"), title= "smt", ylab= "vble",             position = position_dodge(0.3)   )
```

What I need is to change the distance between x ticks, so it represents the actual value of X and not a constant distance such it is now. I thought it was because "month" was a factor, but the result does not change if month is defined as numeric. I also tried setting the breaks with scale_x_continuous and also with scale_x_discret but with no success. 
Does anyone know if is it possible to do and how?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the latest [ggpubr dev version](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/280) available on github. You can install it using the R code devtools::install_github("kassambara/ggpubr").

After installation, you can specify the option `numeric.x.axis = TRUE` to treat x-axis as numeric.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggpubr))

# Demo data
mi_df <- data.frame(
  "month" = as.numeric(rep(c(0, 1, 2, 12, 15, 48), 30)),
  "sust" = as.factor(rep(c(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 6)), 15)),
  "vble" = as.numeric(rnorm(180))
)

# Error plot: x-axis treated as factor (default)
ggerrorplot(
  mi_df,
  x = "month", y = "vble",
  desc_stat = "mean_sd", color = "sust", palette = c("black", "grey"),
  title = "smt", ylab = "vble",
  position = position_dodge(0.3)
)
```

[image]

```r
# Using numeric x axis: numeric.x.axis = TRUE
ggerrorplot(
  mi_df,
  x = "month", y = "vble",
  desc_stat = "mean_sd", color = "sust", palette = c("black", "grey"),
  title = "smt", ylab = "vble",
  position = position_dodge(0.3),
  numeric.x.axis = TRUE
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Comment: Great!! Thank you so much!! That was exactly what I was trying to do.